Route Traffic To VPC Subnets Through OpenVPN Allows Connect To OpenVPN Private IP But No Other Servers
Desired Result
Hello Server Fault.
I have two EC2 instances where one has OpenVPN installed, running, and I can connect to the private IP address for that machine. I have a second ec2 instance with only a private IP address that I am not able to route to currently.
I am use the 10.21.0.0/16 range for a VPC with four subnets. Those subnets use
10.21.0.0/20, public, in us-west-2a
10.21.160.0/20, private, in us-west-2a
10.21.16.0/20, public, in us-west-2b
10.21.176.0/20, private, in us-west-2b

I would like my OpenVPN to only route traffic to the 10.21.0.0/16 range (we'll probably add more subnets later) and to not effect traffic on any other routes. I would also like traffic to originate from VPN box so that I only have to open up ports to traffic internally in the VPC and not to the general internet. So far I'm able to route traffic to the private IP on the VPN box but not to the private test machine.
I thought that using the push "route 10.21.0.0 255.255.0.0" option in my server configuration would cause the client machine to have all connections go through the OpenVPN server but obviously that's not working so I am missing something important in my configuration steps or general networking knowledge.
I'm just going to note that I'm pretty new to setting up my own VPNs.
VPC Diagram

/etc/openvpn/server.conf
kamanda         10081/tcp                       # amanda backup services (Kerberos)
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.21.0.2"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.21.0.2"
push "route 10.21.0.0 255.255.0.0"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_QGf4vWpLakttzNwZ.crt
key server_QGf4vWpLakttzNwZ.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3

.ovpn File
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote {{ public ip }} 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_QGf4vWpLakttzNwZ name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{{ cert }}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{{ cert }}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
{{ cert }}
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
{{ cert }}
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>

Private IP Access Via VPN
% ssh  ubuntu@10.21.6.191
Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-1016-aws aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are
not required on a system that users do not log into.

To restore this content, you can run the 'unminimize' command.
Last login: Sat Oct  5 00:08:14 2024 from 10.8.0.2

Edit: Adding VPC Routing Tables + IP Tables


IP Tables
$ sudo iptables --table nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  ip-10-8-0-0.us-west-2.compute.internal/24  anywhere


You need to be careful AWS not allow traffic forward, I mean you send sent packages that the source address does not belong to the instance, so if you want to forward traffic beyond the endpoint (EC2 with the OpenVPN), you need to enable NAT in this instance.

At the risk of asking the obvious, do the VPC route tables route the VPN client subnet back to the ENI of the instance hosting the VPN, and did you disable the source/dest check on that ENI?

I have disabled the source/dest check on he ENI. I am unsure if I have setup the VPC route tables correctly in this case. I will need to go grab a screenshot later tonight when I am back at my work computer. I assume the public route tables need a specific route between the ENI's IP and the subnets in the VPC?

@Michael-sqlbot I have updated the question to include two of the route tables for a public subnet and private subnet + the IP tables nat configuration.
